# Hadoop Pig correlation usage

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a list of vectors that I want to run correlation against via an input vector (of numbers).  How should I store my list of vectors, and how do I pass in my input vector and pass it to [Pig's COR() function](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/udf_lists.html#)?

```
-- SET command?  what is it used for? this doesn't work
SET input_nums {0,2,0,1,2,0,0,0,0} AS bag{}

-- storing vectors in this format doesn't seem to work 
-- import via: data = LOAD mynums AS (id:long, nums:bag{});
1\t{1,3,3,4,5}
2\t{3,4,5,6,6}

-- this seems to work, but adds overhead on storage
-- import via: data = LOAD mynums AS (id:long, nums:bag{t:(x:long)});
1\t{(1),(3),(3),(4),(5)}
2\t{(3),(4),(5),(6),(6)}

-- assuming "data" and "input_nums" are set, no idea how to use though:
results = COR(data, input_nums) -- nope
results = FOREACH data GENERATE id, COR(nums, input_nums) -- nope
```

Less important side question: I've seen pig scripts that take arguments. Can I pass in my `input_nums` via these arguments (i.e. string argument, then Pig makes into a bag)?

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement with respect to running [`COR`](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/udf_lists.html) in Pig is that the input arguments be bags of doubles. Also, make sure you have a pig version that is >=0.90.1 (refer to [JIRA: PIG-2286](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2286)).

Input data:
`1<tab>10`
`2<tab>12`
`3<tab>13`
`4<tab>14`

Script:
`data = LOAD 'cor.txt' AS (series1:double, series2:double);`
`rel = GROUP data ALL;`
`corop = FOREACH rel GENERATE COR(data.series1, data.series2);`
`dump corop;`

Output:
`({(var0,var1,0.9827076298239908)})`